# Facebook FB.login() API callback not firing

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I'm using FB.login() api with permissions - email and public_profile on a click event. It prompts for credential with facebook dialogue box.
But on filling credentials and clicking login, the callback of FB.login() never gets fired. Also the facebook login is successfully done if checked on facebook.com. 
I'm also using FB.getLoginStatus and it works properly when the user is already logged in. Why the callback of FB.login() api is never firing? My FB.login code is as follows -

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
}, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true});
```

Comment: _“the callback of FB.login() never gets fired”_ - and how exactly do you think you determined that ...? Because you do not get to see the expected console.log output? That is wrapped into an if condition that might simply not be true ...

Comment: Ok, but I tested with console.log outside that if also, then also it did not printed...I have updated my code now.

Comment: Any errors in console? How exactly are you calling this function?

Comment: where is the rest of your code? what browser did you use? use the chrome dev tools, firebug in firefox often has problems with console.log in callback functions.

Comment: Got the issue. Actually the js file in which I have defined the function for FB.login was becoming out of scope just after being called due to change in window.location occurring because of one another event in the app happening simultaneously. So the FB.login function had scope till it was called (displaying FB login box) but due to execution of window.change immediately after it, the callback of FB.login became out of scope. Was kind of tricky to find out. Thanks by the way!